# How to set "hide ribbon" as default in MS Office applications?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there an option to set (I'm specifically asking for MS Word and Outlook when replying to mails) "hide ribbon" (Ctrl + F1) as default option?

Since I'm working on a laptop, and those ribbons with status bars and so on, are leaving less and less space for actual work - writing.

Comment: don't know but just a comment, you might want to use classic menus by addintools.http://www.addintools.com/office2010/professionalplus/index.html

Comment: @barlop - Many thanks! Alas, work computer - I don't have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the ribbon by double clicking the tab, I don't believe it will reopen on restart. Clicking the tab will open it in a sort of temporary way which closes when you select an option. Double clicking should bring it back permanently.